# Search function to retrieve from 4th category php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

Here is my problem...
I have a database.. IE:

```
1 - Antiques - Antique - Clocks - Bracket Clocks
2 - Antiques - Antique - Clocks - Cuckoo Clocks
```

and

```
133 - Art - Artists - Digital Art
134 - Art - Artists - Drawings
142 - Art - Canvas/ Giclee Prints - Animals
```

And so on (2600 rows)
I spent four days doing the database and used alot from eBay's Category list.
Now i'm trying to set up the search function to search on my site through the categories.
The query gets the list from mysql :

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sellit_categories GROUP BY sellitcat ORDER BY `sellitcat` ASC');
    $selectval = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $selectval .= '<option value="'.$row['sellitcatid'].'">'.$row['sellitcat'].'</option>';
    }
```

My problem is i'm unable to search ALL Grouped categories for eg if i try to search in Antiques, the result will ONLY be from the FIRST row ID1 and not searching the whole of Antiques..
Same applies for all the seperate categories..
If i list something in Art - Artist - Drawings then try to search i get no results.

Not sure if i'm being clear about it. Hope you can understand and show me the way forward :D
Thank you!

Comment: As pointed out by @akond below, if this is really your table structure you have a problem. Please update your question with the structure of the relevant tables - `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`. You should probably store this category data in a [nested set structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It is a pain to manage but fast for querying.

Comment: ... or closure tables. Any hierarchical structure will be easier to work with than these strings.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you have chosen for your table is unfortunate. Have a look at http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html for the alternative.